# I am using itext html2pdf dependency to convert plain html and tailwind CSS to pdf in spring boot microservice, only few CSS classes are selected

Tags: spring-boot, pdf, itext, tailwind-css, html2pdf

Few Tailwind CSS classes are not used

below are some errors [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW3IG.png)

other errors [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2ptw.jpg)

my output [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eobC1.png)

Excepted output [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQrDO.png)

Comment: Please do not paste images, here is why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1847378